# How to bind cefpython on the panel(wxpython)?

Tags: wxpython, cefpython

Below specified code for **wxpython GUI** where you can observe I have used the **wx.html2.WebView** to render the web on the panel. Is it possible to replace from **webview** to **cefpython** for the same code?

I also got the **cefpython cod**e that was launching its own frame. I don't want to be open with its own frame instead of that it binds on **wxpython panel**. You can see the cefpython code below.

***1.wxpython GUI Code***

```
import wx
import sys
import wx.html2 

def main(args):
    app = CefApp(False, args)
    app.MainLoop()

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.frame = parent

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        self.wv = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
        closeBtn = wx.Button(self, label="X", size=(30, 30))
        closeBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.Add(closeBtn, 0, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALL)
        vbox.Add(hbox, 0, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        vbox.SetSizeHints(self)
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)

        sizer.Add(closeBtn, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALL)
        sizer.Add(self.wv, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.wv.LoadURL("http://google.com")

    def onClose(self, event):
        dlg = DialogBox()
        dlg.ShowModal()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, args):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="ESSB Demo")
        self.url = args
        self.browser_panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.ShowFullScreen(True)
```

***2.CefPython Code.***

```
from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
import platform
import sys


def main():
    sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error
    cef.Initialize()
    cef.CreateBrowserSync(url="https://www.google.com/")
    cef.MessageLoop()
    cef.Shutdown()
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cefpython code you provided comes from the hello_wordl.py example. That example does not support wxpython. Example of embedding CEF browser in a wxpython application inside a panel is available in the wxpython.py example:

https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/wxpython.py